# Migration from TargetSDKVersion 22 to 26, toolbar menu icon size issue

Tags: android

Recently I'm moving project from `TargetSDKVersion` 22 to 26. Everything works fine. But I found `toolbar` menu icon size shrinks considerably in my Android 4.4 Moto E. Here is the `gradle` changes,

```
dependencies {

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
}
```

[image: Earlier it was like this]

[image: Now it looks like this.]

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Icons are imported using Batch importer to all drawable folders.

Menu xml,

```
<group android:id="@+id/grpa">
<item
    android:id="@+id/copyData"
    android:icon="@drawable/copy"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/string_copy"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
</item>
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/grpb">
<item
    android:id="@+id/pasteData"
    android:title="@string/string_paste"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:icon="@drawable/paste"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
</item>
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/grpc">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action1"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:title="@string/action_something"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</group>
```

Comment: Please post your menu xml and drawable files

Comment: @Umang Burman, please check my post, i updated with menu xml.

Comment: try adding compile `'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0'` and sync.

Comment: no, didn't work

Comment: The problem is with the batch importer which you are using for the drawables. Try adding the icons manually and see if it's working as you need it.